# Hide span if a related div has img src""

Tags: jquery, if-statement, image, src

I'm a new bee here... I have been fighting with jquery for a while. (in my learning curve)

This is what i m trying to do:

I'm using a list as below:

```
<ul>
<li class="li-listb"><span id="banner1">Banner I</span></li>   
<li class="li-listb"><span id="banner2">Banner II</span></li>           
</ul>
```

and use Jquery

```
<script>
$(function () {

// Make the divs have equal heights
var h1 = $("#div1").height();
var h2 = $("#div2").height();
$("#div1,#div2").height(Math.max(h1, h2));

// Then hide the second div
$("#div2").hide();

// Then add a click handlers to the buttons
$("#banner1").click(function () {
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").hide();
});
$("#banner2").click(function () {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
});
})</script>
```

I link the span to the below divs

```
<div class="workspace">
<div id="div1">
<img src="http://weareunio.com/unio/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/728x901.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<img src=""/>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to hide Span #banner2 when div2 img src="" is empty.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Shree

http://jsfiddle.net/Yx5hu/

Comment: Hi, this is an easy thing, but is you have something much more than this, a jsfiddle can help :)

Comment: @Caramba - Tried Didn't work! http://jsfiddle.net/Yx5hu/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("ul li").each(function(index){
 if($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src') == "")
    $(this).hide()
});
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Yx5hu/4/)**

This will work for any number of `li`s and `div`s provided their ids matches

Comment: Great guys .... I was struck with this for about a week..... Great support guys.... Wonderfull thanks a million

Comment: Hey, you are checking whether the `div` exists.. instead you should try the code in my answer `if($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src') == "")`.. i.e. check for `src` attribute of image inside the div

Comment: I was trying with div & img exists as well... please check now... i m using your code only... still its not working there... it works fine in jsfiddle.... Please help A.V

Comment: Can you please try `alert($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src'));` just before the `if` condition..?

Comment: @A.V Updated. Still no luck.

Comment: @A.V Yes.... This is what i have now :
'$("ul li").each(function(index){
 alert($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src'));
 if($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src') == null)
    $(this).hide()
});'

Comment: Ok , I think  i got it now.. remove that line and put rest of the code inside : `$(function () { //code here });`

Comment: Code should look like : `$(function (){
$("ul li").each(function(index){
 if($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src') == null)
    $(this).hide()
});
});`

Comment: @A.V - is this correct :<code>
$(function () {
$("ul li").each(function(index){
 if($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src') == null)
    $(this).hide()
});</code>

Comment: Or try: `$(document).ready(function() {  $("ul li").each(function(index){ if($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src') == null) $(this).hide() }); });`

Comment: $(document).ready(function{ $("ul li").each(function(index){ if($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src') == null) $(this).hide() }); });
--- This is what i have!

Comment: @A.V Sorry I just copied the code... Not sure how it got missed!

Comment: @A.V I guess i have it right now! still no luck! Is this because of using Jquery link version 1.9.1

Comment: Now can you put the `alert($('#div'+ (index+1) + ' img' ).attr('src'));` inside `.each`...

Comment: @A.V I get alerts now with image urls and blank alerts as well! but the span is not hiding... should i try to $(this).addclass(hidden)

Comment: @A.V Nothing yet... Trying with $('span #banner'+ index+1) .hide()

Comment: @Shree , use the code as  in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yx5hu/10/, I'm sure the problem will be solved...

Comment: @A.V Perfect Solution. IT worked like magic... What was the problem?

Comment: Empty `img` source can be `null` or empty string... First I was checking only `null`.. Glad to know its solved now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

check following code

```
<ul>
   <li class="li-listb"><span id="banner1">Banner I</span></li>   
   <li class="li-listb"><span id="banner2">Banner II</span></li>           
</ul>
<div class="workspace">
 <div id="div1">
   <img src="http://weareunio.com/unio/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/728x901.jpg"/>
 </div>
<div id="div2">
   <img src=""/>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
$("div.workspace div").each(function(index){    
var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
var n = ($(this).attr("id")).substring(3);
if(src == "")
{
    var bnrID = "#banner"+n;
    $(bnrID).hide();
}
});
```